# MongoDB connection working without authentication on Docker / Windows Server 2019

Tags: c#, mongodb, docker, .net-core, webapi

I have a .NET core WebAPI application that connects to a MongoDB inside a Docker container. I'm running Windows Server 2019. Initially I set everything up and confirmed it worked, and then decided to add authentication (MongoDb root/pass). However creating an enirely new container and volume with the correct auth arguments, the API calls are still working correctly and not failing due to unauthenticated access.

When I try to connect to the MongoDb using authorization, it doesn't connect but does connect when I use no authentication.

This initial code to create the container without authentication (worked):
`docker run -d --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017  -v C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes\mongodbdata:C:\data\db mongo`

Then I ran
`docker stop mongo`
`docker volume rm mongodbdata`

And the new container with authentication (which is not authenticating but still connects when no auth is selected):

`docker run -d --rm --name mongo -p 27017:27017  -v C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes\mongodbdataauth:C:\data\db -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=mongoadmin -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password mongo`

[image: Here is a screenshot from Portainer confirming the containers existence]

[image: Showing authentication isn't working]

[image: Same db with connection succeeding and no auth]

[image: Response from API & MongoDb showing data is stored correctly and returning]

I have look all around the internet but can't find anything so far that pertains to my issue. I cannot find one reason why this should be still happening.The use of absolute paths in the "C:\ProgramData\docker\volumes\mongodbdataauth:C:\data\db" argument was needed to make it work the first time. I've deleting, renaming, creating different paths and volumes but none of this had an effect. The issue is just the authentication and I haven't found anything that fits my problem.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: I am not familiar with docker but according screenshot it starts the process with `mongod --bind_ip_all`. By default authentication is disabled, i.e. docker starts the MongoDB without authentication.

Comment: You can (almost) always connect to a MongoDB without credentials even when authentication is enabled. However, you cannot execute any command apart from harmless commands like `db.help()`, `db.listCommands()`, `db.getMongo()` or `db.auth(..., ...)` to authenticate

Comment: The example I've been watching that goes through this, running the same command and code, doesn't allow the postman GET requests to receive and succeeds with the VS Code Mongo authenticated connection. Not sure why mine is behaving differently.